# How to send weekly priorities email from MS Project

Tags: software-development, ms-project

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory, but let me clarify. I'd like to send a mail to each member of the development team each Monday, which outlines the tasks that they should focus on for the week, along with completion dates.

I'd like something automated, but the team is small enough that I can do some manual work if needed.

Or perhaps someone knows of a better way to ensure everyone knows what they are supposed to be working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar as required (biweekly or thereabouts), alerting the team to tasks coming up in the next 2-3 months on an 18 month project. I notify the entire team and hgihlight who should be doing what manually rather than automatically since (a) our team is small enough to handle this and (b) I find that humans pay more attention to other humans than to automatic notifications.

To do this, MS Project has a function that allows you to filter tasks based on start/completion dates. In Project 2007 you'll see a combo box at the top right of the screen, probably defaulting to "All Tasks". Choose the date range you want with the info you need and send this to your team along with any encouraging words that you need to motivate them. I usually highlight them as well as a visual reminder to myself when I'm updating the Gantt based on current progress.

Comment: So filter, copy and paste? That's so elegant that I feel a little silly trying to arm-wrestle the built-in reports into doing what I want! Thank you.